# What command I use to change file permission using ftps connection?

Tags: c#, linux, unix, file-permissions, ftps

My application need to change remote file permission after upload (STOR). It is using ftps connection for this.
What is the correct command for this, similar to chmod command?
I searched [FTP Commands and Extensions](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ftp-commands-extensions/ftp-commands-extensions.xhtml) and I not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being ftps does not change the way to change the permissions. It was enough to use what already exists in a simple FTP connection:

```
site chmod file_name desired_permission
```